# Kernel function between time series of different lengths

Tags: time-series, svm, kernel-trick

I'm studying a data set composed of time series of different lengths; some are up to an order of magnitude longer than others. (If it matters, the data aren't actually *temporally* related; it's just that the elements have an inherent ordering. In turn, adjacent values are typically similar.)

It would be interesting to define a kernel function between two such vectors, but their differing lengths is a stumbling block in applying generic approaches like linear, polynomial or RBF kernel functions.

Are there kernel functions defined over variable-length sequences?